# Update function not working in MS Access Userform

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, userform

```
Private Sub Command15_Click()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim db As Database
    Dim RST As Variant
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set RST = db.OpenRecordset("SSPTab")
    
    With RST
    .Edit
    .Fields(6) = Me.Reviewersname
    .Fields(9) = Me.Assessments
    .Fields(11) = Me.Review_Comments
    .Fields(7) = Me.Reviewstatus
    .Update
    End With
```

*I would like to open the existing row details and make changes to it and update. The above code is working fine for me except .Fields(7) , showing data conversion error.*

Comment: I tried the below but this is showing syntax error

Comment: CurrentDb.Execute "Update From SSPTab Set [Reviewer]='" & Me.Reviewersname & " ',[Assessment]='" & Me.Assessments & "',[Review Comments]='" & Me.Review_Comments & "',ReviewStatus='" & Me.ReviewsStatus & "' Where RITM=" & Val(Reviewspending)

Comment: You should edit question to show that attempt. Have you step debugged? What data type is ReviewStatus? What is the content of Me.ReviewStatus?

Comment: didnt get u....

Comment: Reivew Status is Short Text, it has value list like completed,initated

Comment: Then cannot explain failure. Is this 'userform' a form within Access? Why not use bound form and controls? Open form to desired record and control inputs should go directly into table.

Comment: Not sure how to do it

Comment: How to do what - build a form in Access? That's basic Access functionality.

Comment: How is `OpenRecordset("SSPTab")` opening the existing row? is SSPTab a query or table with only one row (and it is the current row) you want to update? Please include the table structure for SSPTab (column names, types). Also do a debug.print of Me.Revieversname, ... just before the With stmt and show us those (you can replace real names with xxx, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Use proper declarations:

```vb
Private Sub Command15_Click()

    Dim db  As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("SSPTab")
    
    With rst
        .Edit
        .Fields(6).Value = Me!Reviewersname.Value
        .Fields(9).Value = Me!Assessments.Value
        .Fields(11).Value = Me!Review_Comments.Value
        ' Field 7 must be Short Text or Long Text.
        ' .Fields(7).Value = Me!Reviewstatus.Value
        .Fields(7).Value = Me!Revstats.Value
        .Update
        .Close
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Still am getting the error as 3421 ..current data type is long

Comment: That explains. There is no way assigning text to a field of data type Long.

Comment: I modified the field names and changed the way of doing like below

Comment: If Me.Reviewspending = " " Then
    Exit Sub
    Else
    CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE SSPTab  " & _
    "SET [Reviewer]=" & Me.Reviewersname.Value & _
    ", [Statusofreview]='" & Me.Revstats.Value & "'" & _
    ", [Assessment]='" & Me.Assessments.Value & "'" & _
    ", [Review Comments]='" & Me.Review_Comments.Value & "'" & _
    " WHERE [RITM]=" & Me.Reviewspending.Value
    
    End If

Comment: Now facing the syntax error in UPdate statement...issue...3144 error

Comment: Can anyone please help me out....

Comment: That change - using concatenated SQL - won't help, only complicates matters, as you can see. If Field 7 is `[Statusofreview]` and still of data type Long, you can't assign it a text value. And check your spelling of the assigning control: `Reviewstatus` or `Revstats`?

Comment: spellings are correct....I meant I wantedly mentioned in that way

Comment: So what is the name of the control holding the status? It can't have two names.

Comment: Can I have ur email id

Comment: Statusofreview is in table, Long data type. Revstats is in form

Comment: You mean _Long Text_? If so, then all you need is to use the right name of the control on the form - see edited answer, please.

Comment: have you changed the code above?

Comment: Yes, because you changed the name of the control. Click the _edited xx mins ago_ link.